# Can't Move Mouse When Key Pressed

Tags: arch-linux, i3, touchpad, xinput, asus

I'm running up-to-date arch on an Asus G15 (2021) and I'm using `i3` as my WM.

I can't for the life of me, work out why the trackpad doesn't seem to work when I have a key pressed down.

Where would I even start with this one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, there was a property on my trackpad that was set to disable when typing by default.

To solve, use `xinput` to find the device ID of the trackpad:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Asus Keyboard                             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUE1209:00 04F3:319F Mouse               id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ASUE1209:00 04F3:319F Touchpad            id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

In this case, ID=13.

Then, use `xinput list-props $dev-id` to list all the available properties, the one I wanted was:

```
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (344):    1
libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (345):    1
```

The ID of the property I wanted to change was 344, this might vary by device.

And finally, I can use `xinput set-prop $dev-id $prop-id 0` to disable that property.

So the full command, using the IDs on my laptop was:

`xinput set-prop 13 336 0`